# how to set default printer in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10, qml

i have an app that should print a paper in 3 printer that one of them is local and 2 others are shared from server the local printer is good but for print to shared printer i have problem in Win 10 i should choose one of them as default printer to print . so the second shared printer don't print because it is not default printer.i use this:

```
QString Services::print(QVariant data , int id){
    QString mess="ss";
    QImage img = qvariant_cast<QImage>(data);
    QPrinter printer_(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    QStringList name;
    name=readSettings();
    if(name.at(id)==""){
        return "please enter the printer name ";
    }
    else{
        printer_.setPrinterName(name.at(id));
        printer_.setResolution(300);
        printer_.setCopyCount(1);
        printer_.setDoubleSidedPrinting(false);
        printer_.setDuplex(QPrinter::DuplexNone);
        printer_.setColorMode(QPrinter::Color);
        printer_.setPageSize(QPrinter::A5);
        printer_.setPaperSource(QPrinter::Auto);
        printer_.setCreator("serverApp");
        printer_.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);

        printer_.setDocName("factor");

        printer_.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);

        if (!printer_.isValid())
           return "printer not valid";

         QPainter painter(&printer_);
         QImage img2 =img.scaled(img.width()*1.65,img.height()*1.7);
         painter.drawImage(QPoint(0,0),img2);
         qDebug()<<printer_.printerState();

        switch(printer_.printerState()){
        case QPrinter::Idle:
            mess="don't send";
            break;
        case QPrinter::Active:
            mess="send";
            break;
        case QPrinter::Aborted:
            mess="cancell";
            break;
        case QPrinter::Error:
            mess="error";
            break;

        }
        painter.end();
        return mess;
    }}
```

in the other words is there any way to set default printer in Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure out the problem , for shared printers that aren't default we should set the printer name like this: "\\name of computer server\the real printer name in server"